# (SpotFire) Aggregated Average

Tags: spotfire

I have a challenge.

See example data below.

```
ID Prod Weight Mnd Year 
1  XXX  2344   Jun 2018 
2  XXX  2344   Jun 2018 
3  ZZZ  3344   Jun 2018 
4  ZZZ  3344   Jun 2018 
5  ZZZ  3344   Jun 2018 
6  ZZZ  3344   Jun 2018
```

I'm looking for a calculated column to show the average per month/year.

Problem is: amount of rows differs for the products. If I do an AVERAGE then the Product with the most rows has a bigger influence on the outcome then it should. In above example "AVERAGE([Weight]) over ([Month],[Year])" doesn't work. In this example the outcome of the formule is 3011 (wrong) iso 2844 (correct).

Any tips how to solve this.

Comment: Your example would be a lot better if you showed us what the data really looks like? All your months are the same so why do you need the months column? Same with years? Why not just take unique rows and take the average from there?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding a pivot table. File > Add Data Tables > Add > Choose your table. You may want to rename the new table by appending "_pivot" to the table name. Then in the transformations part of the window, choose Pivot from the drop down and then click the "Add..." button. For row identifiers, choose `Prod`, `Weight`, `Mnd` and `Year`. Note that I have omitted the `ID` column. Click OK. Then choose "Calculate new column" in the transformations drop down. You can now add your calculated column. Once you do, hit OK until the Add Data Tables window closes.